# Comparison of time-dependent traveling salesman heuristics

Tags: np-complete, reference-request, dynamic-programming, heuristics, traveling-salesman

I'm looking into implementing a heuristic for the time-dependent traveling traveling salesman problem (TDTSP) that completes in a certain amount of time.

There are a wide range of possible ways to approach the problem, from dynamic programming to simulated annealing to genetic programming.

How do these approaches compare? Are there any metastudies on this?

Comment: This run-down of TSP heuristics might prove useful: http://web.tuke.sk/fei-cit/butka/hop/htsp.pdf

Comment: Also, results from the Kiwi.com competition might be helpful here: https://travellingsalesman.cz/ . The winning contestant used simulated annealing, as described at https://github.com/ptrmtrx/travelling_salesman .